# how to setup a excel chart with data points

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel spreadsheet that has been exported from a kendo-ui grid. I have zero experience with excel and I need help turning this data into a excel chart. the attached spreadsheet is what i am working with. Every subdivision name is its own series with (sqft,price) points. is there a way to make one chart with the supplied data?

attached is link to the excel spreadsheet

[excel spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-zrEeoOpFm4dmNKbkpxSWJwZU0/view?usp=sharing)

update from first answer

[image: update from first answer]

Comment: The screenshot is not what's in the Google spreadsheet. If the target is moving, it's really hard to hit. What is your question now? What kind of chart do you want? Mock up the chart with the drawing tools, so we know what to aim for.

Comment: manager just gave new marching orders. going a different direction. thanks for the reply.i will know how to ask next time. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a table with just one header-row (create a new column for the Arbor .. Values).

The value of this column is the name for the diagram line (instead of serie1 etc.)

Comment: actually i just made a change. I think I am on right track?